# ./configure.sh while installing CHARM toolkit giving unsuccessful results

Tags: 12.04

following is result snapshot of ./configure.sh -

```
CFLAGS            -O2 -g 
CHARM_CFLAGS       -m32 -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes  -fstack-protector-all -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits
LDFLAGS           -m32 
make              make
python            /usr/bin/python3
build_ext options build_ext 
install           install
host CPU          i386
wget              /usr/bin/wget
gprof enabled     no
profiler          no
static build      no
-Werror enabled   no
integer module    yes
ecc module        yes
pairing module    yes
disable benchmark no
libm found        yes
libgmp found      yes
libpbc found      no
libcrypto found   yes
Documentation     no
```

How to "enable" and convert "No"s to "Yes", because this problem is making problem in make command(running after this) also?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can run configure.sh with the --help option to get help - like:

```
./configure.sh --help
```

In the help text you can see your options. To disable the integer module you could write:

```
./configure.sh --disable-integer
```

Together with any other options you will like to change away from the default.